# .net WinForms control validation - how to explicitly validate all controls

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

If I create a simple Winforms app with a button and a textbox, and the following event handlers, I'd expect to see "False" when I hit the button.  When I hit the button, it actually produces "True".

Why is the form valid?  It doesn't appear that the validating event is executing at all, even though [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50w40fty.aspx) say that passing false causes validation to be performed unconditionally.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.Validate(false).ToString());
    }

    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to validate a child control of the Form. If that's the case, you should use one of the `ValidateChildren` methods instead of `Validate`.